# Alsa: snd_pci_readi() and real-time threads

Tags: pthreads, audio-recording, alsa

I've got a dedicated thread that caputures audio from Alsa through snd_pcm_readi(). Periodically I get a short read, meaning snd_pcm_readi() returns a positive integer lower than my buffer size, and there's obviously a 'pop' sound in my audio stream. Then I set the thread priority to real-time and this gives a tangible benefit, far less short reads, but this doesn't solve.

Now the question: before going down the bumpy road of a real-time patched Linux kernel, there's something else I can do to squeeze out some more performance? Is calling snd_pcm_readi() in a dedicated thread the best way to pull audio out of Alsa?

Comment: What are the period/buffers sizes? Why?

Comment: period size is 512 samples. I'm using, on purpose, a crappy usb audio dongle to test my system in hard conditions. Short reads are infrequent, let's say one every 30 seconds on average, so I'm wondering if can write better code instead of increasing the period size.

Comment: What is the buffer size?

Comment: 1024 as of the output of snd_pcm_dump().

Comment: Why? The buffer size does not affect latency; make it as large as possible.

Comment: Because... mmmh... lets say I learned something :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playback, the buffer size determines the latency.

For capture, it does not; only the period size determines how long you must wait until recorded samples are reported to be available.
So to prevent overruns, make the buffer as large as possible (e.g., by calling `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_max()` after setting the other parameters).